# Почему меню Materialize CSS не сворачивается?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize-css

Использую библиотеку Materialize CSS.
На их основном сайте все работает, у меня нет:

[image: меню]

Почему меню не до конца сворачивается?
Если смотреть на десктопе, то все нормально сворачивается, на мобильнике нет.

Код HTML:

```
  <nav>
       <div class="nav-wrapper">
         <a class="brand-logo">{{ titlelogo }}</a>
         <a data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
         </a>

        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
           <li><a class="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown2">Задачи <i class="count-work" ng-class="{notification: tasks.length != 0 }">{{ tasks.length }}</i></a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown1">Профиль <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
         </ul>

        <!-- dropdown -->
         <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
           <li><a><b>Пользователь (Иванов М.А)</b></a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>

           <li>
             <a><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Настройки пользователя</a>
           </li>

           <li class="divider"></li>

           <li>
            <a ng-click="closeSession()">
            <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Выйти из системы
            </a>
           </li>
         </ul>

         <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">

           <li ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="openTask($event, task.idmyprocess)" data-id-task-myprocess="{{ task.idmyprocess }}">
            <a> {{ task.Caption }} </a>
           </li>

         </ul>




        <!-- mobile menu -->
         <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
           <li><a><b>Пользователь (Иванов М.А)</b></a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li><a>Архив процессов</a></li>
           <li><a>Задачи</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li><a>Настройки пользователя</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li><a ng-click="closeSession()">Выйти из системы</a></li>
         </ul>

       </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: вероятно, оно сворачивается позиционированием. а если так, то надо проверить, какие параметры заданы для отступов слева/справа

Comment: такое срабатывает только если пальцем вправо или влево листать (вытаскивать или сворачивать меню)